# Installing MacOS High Sierra on a Macbook Pro 17 mid 2010, after formatting the drive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, ssd

There is a 2010 Macbook, in which the hdd disk was replaced with x2 Samsung ssd 860 evo 500gb.

Foolishly, I decided to roll High Sierra. I formatted the disk, I'm waiting, but nothing loads (it crashes with an error). After studying a bunch of forums and articles, I came to the conclusion that for some reason you can’t put HS on poppies that have non-original HDDs. I decided to put El Capitan back, which apparently stood for a reason, after replacing the hdd, but I don’t understand how to do it.

At the moment I'm trying to combine them through REID 0 and install the High Sierra, but nothing works for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have a working Mac to assist with this effort? Other than using old installers with invalid / expired signing certificates, nothing should prevent either High Sierra or El Capitan from installing on a bare drive on your Mac.

Comment: I have a macbook m1, will it work? Also added screenshots to the post.

Comment: I seem to remember that High Sierra needs updated EFI partition firmware, which must be on the internal drive. It's possible that you need to update to Sierra first, then High Sierra.

Comment: The firmware upgrade accompanied with a High Sierra install is not stored in the EFI partition. In other words, after the firmware upgrade is installed, removing the EFI partition on the internal drive does not remove the firmware upgrade.